# How do I install "GNU IceCat" for Trisquel on Ubuntu?

Tags: icecat

I'm wishing to install **GNU IceCat** on Ubuntu. No Debian package is provided in Ubuntu or by the IceCat team. However, I've found some [Debian packages](http://packages.trisquel.info/search?keywords=icecat) (dead link) from Trisquel GNU/Linux.

How can I install IceCat using these packages?

Another question is, there is two option for IceCat, `belenos` and `belenos-updates`. Which one should I use?

Comment: it may be easier to install the binary, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/817676

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debian packages should be fine, Ubuntu is based on and uses Debian packages.

> "belenos and belenos-updates"

The updates version will get updates that are still in testing and the normal one will get them once they are considered `stable`.

What one should you use?

That is up to you, do you want stability or do you want the latest updates (with potential bugs)?

Comment: Thanks. Here, the term "Debian packages" means ".deb" files. 

Comment: @NaveNobel Yes it does. If this answer is satisfactory, please click the check mark on the left to let others know this was the correct answer.